# jQuery code not executing - iPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone

Im using jquery in webview 
basically im calling jquery method inside the html string loaded inside the
webview.
problem is webview is loaded properly but method is getting executed.
i tried putting breakpoints it's hard to see the execution inside the string.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the Targets - 
JQuery Library should be in the Copy Bundle Resource,
By default it's in the Compile Sources

Drag file from Compile Sources to Copy Bundle Sources.
then try.. hopefully it should work